# plotting exponentialfunction with matrix product inside

Tags: matlab

I got a function y which i want to plot:

```
beta = [1 2];
x = 0:100;
y = exp( beta * [x, 1] );
```

Beta is a 2 dimensional vector and is to be multiplied with a two dimensional (transposed) vector (x,1) where x is a scalar value between 0 and 100.

I would like to plot this graph with

```
plot( x, y );
```

Right now I get the error

```
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
```

since i believe x is some kind of range object.

How can I plot this function?

Comment: Why not just `y = exp(beta(1)*x + beta(2)); plot( x,y)`? Or, if you prefer to use matrix multiplication, you need to replicate that `1` and concatenate it as a second row below `x`: `y = exp(beta*[x; ones(1,numel(x))])`

Comment: Works fine. Thank you. I tried to extend the function to `y = exp(beta(1)*x + beta(2)) / ( 1 + exp(beta(1)*x + beta(2)) )` However the script runs without errors but produces no graph. Since I plottet divisor and dividend aswell there are no weird values involed. Any idea? I use beta =[ 0.0077    0.0003]

Comment: That's because you are using matrix division, which in this case gives a single number, and thus the plot is a single point. You probably want _element-wise_ division, which is `./`,  not `/`. So: `y = exp(beta(1)*x + beta(2)) ./ ( 1 + exp(beta(1)*x + beta(2)) )`. You should really get yourself a basic Matlab tutorial

Comment: Thanks a lot, that solves the Problem. I will look into a Matlab tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
beta = [1 2];
x = 0:99;
z = ones(1,100);
y = exp( beta * [x;z] );
plot( x, y );
```

Comment: Works fine. Thank you. now I would like to extend the function like `y = exp( beta * [x;z] ) / ( 1 + exp( beta * [x;z] ) )` However the script runs without errors but does not show a graph. Since I plotted the graph for the divisor and dividend aswell i am sure there are no weird values involved.

Comment: Solved. See comment on problem description.